# Call an activity from Koin module

Tags: android, api, rest, kotlin, okhttp

I'm trying to logout user in case of a 401 response from any API call in the project.

I'm using Koin Module. Here's the code snippet of Koin Module:

```
single {
        retrofit(get())
    }

single {
        client()
    }


private fun retrofit(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
    val gson = GsonBuilder()
        .setLenient()
        .create()
    return Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(Config.BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build()
}

private fun client(): OkHttpClient {
    val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
    interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
    return OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .writeTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .addInterceptor(object : Interceptor {
            @Throws(IOException::class)
            override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
                val request: Request = chain.request()
                val response: Response = chain.proceed(request)

                // todo deal with the issues the way you need to
                if (response.code == 200) {
                    
                    //Open LogIn Activity
                }
                return response
            }
        }).build()
}
```

How can I call activity from within the interceptor? Or is there any other preferred way to do this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When the API is going to send 401? Check retrofit Authenticator.

Comment: Yes, when the API sends 401 I want to logout the user and redirect to the login screen. The issue I'm facing is I need context to start activity but since I'm using Koin I don't know how to fo that

Comment: Remove the Interceptor from here. Create a separate class and pass the application class object as the param and then you can start the activity from the application class.